# Grandnode upload video

Tags: c#

Can Grandnode upload video? 
Because I tried to upload video but it says upload failed.
When I run from local, it says that "Parameter is not valid".

In this project, I want to have a function that can upload video but I tried to upload video from the button "Upload a file", it says upload fail, I tried to change the extension of the video to image extension but it still says fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you need add new picture you can only upload picture type file (jpg, png, bmp, jpeg). You can't upload video file.